# Django Rest framework - generic view

Tags: python, django, rest

I am learn Django and Django REST framework.
I'm trying to do API and add permissions to view.

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

My models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Word(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='word')
```

My serialazer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from myapp.models import Profile, Word
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile

        fields = ('id', 'nickname', 'user')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = ('id', 'username', 'profile')


class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Word

        fields = ('id', 'value', 'user')
```

My Views:

```
class WordList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Word.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WordSerializer


class WordDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Word.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WordSerializer
```

**when I try add new "word" - show error:**

```
Cannot assign "[]": "Word.user" must be a "User" instance.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/words/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "[]": "Word.user" must be a "User" instance.
Exception Location: /home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in __set__, line 337
Python Executable:  /home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/bin/python3.3
Python Version: 3.3.5
Python Path:    
['/home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/bin/mysite',
 '/home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/lib/python3.3/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/lib/python3.3',
 '/home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/lib/python3.3/plat-linux',
 '/home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.3',
 '/usr/lib/python3.3/plat-linux',
 '/home/mikhail/virtualenv/test/lib/python3.3/site-p
```

**problem in the serializer or view?
How to fix?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sending a POST request to create your word record, you are sending a list (and an empty list at that) for the user attribute of the word, where the framework is expecting a User.

There are a few things I see with the code you posted:

1. With the way you set up your models, a Word can have ONE user, but a User can have many Words.  Is this what you intended?  If yes, then I don't think you should be specifying many=True in your serializer for Word.
2. Is it possible to have a Word without a User?  In that case you might want to make it possible to have the user field to allow None.
3. What does the JSON look like that you are posting?  To create a word (and this from the top of my head, based on what I see) you should be sending something like this:

   {
      'value': 'testWord'
      'user' : 1
   }

Where the value of user is the primary key of the user you want to associate with the word.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood the params meaning of "many=True"  (i deleted it and all work).